# pgfplots with inline data stored in macro in beamer article mode

Tags: beamer, pgfplots, beamerarticle

I used `pgfplots.sty` to draw a plot inside presentation. Data for the plot I generate inside `\foreach` loop and store in a macro. This works fine in presentation mode but when using `beamerarticle` package and `article` class many errors are shown.

The sample code is below:

```
%\documentclass{beamer}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\tablebody{x,y\\}
\makeatletter
\foreach \x in {1,2,3,4}{
  \FPeval\s{clip(x*x)}
  \protected@xappto\tablebody{\x,\s\\} 
}
\makeatother

\begin{frame}{Title}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=5,ymin=0,ymax=20]
        \edef\plotargs{[blue] table[col sep=comma,row sep=\\]{\tablebody}}
        \expandafter\addplot\plotargs;
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Is any way to show the plot in article mode using `beamerarticle`?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious problem is with `\\` that never survives `\edef` or `\xdef`. With your `\protected@xappto` you get `\protect\\` which is invalid in the argument to `\addplot`.

You *might* add suitable `\noexpand` tokens:

```
%\documentclass{beamer}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\tablebody{x,y\noexpand\\}
\makeatletter
\foreach \x in {1,2,3,4}{
  \FPeval\s{clip(x*x)}
  \xappto\tablebody{\x,\s\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\\} 
}
\makeatother

\begin{frame}{Title}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=5,ymin=0,ymax=20]
        \edef\plotargs{[blue] table[col sep=comma,row sep=\noexpand\\]{\tablebody}}
        \expandafter\addplot\plotargs;
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This way you store `\\` as `\noexpand\\` inside `\tablebody` and the final `\edef` will transform them into `\\`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this workaround will cause other problems down the road, but you could get your document to compile like this:

```
%\documentclass{beamer}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand<>{\\}{\only#1{\beameroriginal\\}}
\renewcommand<>{\@centercr}{\only#1{\beameroriginal\@centercr}}
\renewcommand<>{\@normalcr}{\only#1{\beameroriginal\@normalcr}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\tablebody{x,y\\}
\makeatletter
\foreach \x in {1,2,3,4}{
  \FPeval\s{clip(x*x)}
  \protected@xappto\tablebody{\x,\s\\} 
}
\makeatother

\begin{frame}{Title}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=5,ymin=0,ymax=20]
        \edef\plotargs{[blue] table[col sep=comma,row sep=\\]{\tablebody}}
        \expandafter\addplot\plotargs;
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```